# Snyk Security Scan task in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, snyk

I am trying to use Snyk Security Scan task in Azure Pipeline (Classic). My Application runtime is .Net and framework is ASP.Net 4.4.1 . There is no issue regarding authentication as i had create valid service connection of Snyk.

When i am running my pipeline it is giving error "Could not detect supported target files in D:\a\1\s".

log of failed Snyk Security Scan task:

##[debug]debug=undefined

---

##[debug]task result: Failed
** We have a problem! :( **
##[error]There was an error when attempting to execute the process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]There was an error when attempting to execute the process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT

---

There was an error when attempting to execute the process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]There was an error when attempting to execute the process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use hosted agent or self-hosted agent to run ?

Comment: I had used hosted agent @penaunt

Comment: @ShivamSingh did you resolve this? I get the same error on some pipelines

Comment: @ShivamSingh this question is pretty old now - did you resolve it or is it still a problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and needed to take advantage of the "Custom path to manifest file to test" field with an absolute location of the packages file: C:\agent_work[buildId]\s[solution folder][project folder]\packages.config

This was running on a private build server.